# Boostrap Tooltip CSS not working on AJAX dynamic content

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am having issues with bootstrap tooltips, whereby tooltips are working (in terms of function(showing on hover, left position etc)). But they are not styled!

I have an ajax that gathers data into a table and dumps that html into a container using .html(response)

I can understand if the functionality wasn't working as the elements are loaded after the DOM load, but why is it that the styling is not being applied?

The stylesheet is included in a <>php include() ?> and it works on all other pages, so the stylesheets are being loaded.

I have attempted initializing the tooltips in many locations to see if styling gets applied properly eg:

```
$('body').tooltip({
    selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"]'
});
```

Including every time the ajax gets triggered:

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

Is there a reason why this would occur? Is CSS applied to tooltips on DOM load?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `the ajax gets triggered` - can you be more specific?  Just before `$.ajax` ?

Comment: That is purely for info on the setup. The issue is the CSS not loading. The actual functionality works. So when I initialize .tooltip(), that works. Each icon has a tooltip function. The issue is that they are not styling. This leads me to believe that it has something to do with the fact that the data (rows of tables) (which have tooltips on them) are being loaded into the page AFTER the .tooltip() is initialized?

Comment: I have also noticed that when hovering over the element to show the tooltip, not only does it show absolute full width on the page (as no styling), but also adds the tooltip to the end of the page and keeps it there forever...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**:
jQuery UI js conflicted with bootstrap's tooltip.

**Solution**:
Only included the tabs UI element instead of the entire UI framework